# How to hide elements in graphical layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have items in my View which are displayd on click and does not show up on that start of the activity.
Now everything works fine but when i use the graphical layout tool i see those items and it makes working with it harder.

Meaning, i have a ListView with items, i see those items on top of everything.

How can i hide those elements? setting the visibility programaticlly dosen't help.
Should i do something like setting alpha to 0 and then add it instead of making items invisible?
Seems like a dumb idea, there must be some option i'm missing.

Help anyone?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Why not set the visibility to 'gone': `android:visibility="gone"`? That will prevent layout items from showing up *and* taking up space in the layout.

Alternatively, if some elements in your view hierarchy may never be shown to the user at all, you could use [`ViewStub`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html)s to 'lazily' load them at runtime. A `ViewStub` is simply a placeholder for some other view (hierarchy) and is empty and zero-sized by itself. It's a good way of separating your view hierarchy into default and optional elements, and can potentialy reduce the complexity of the view hierarchy at runtime significantly.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to hide the element programmatically / conditionally instead of in the layout XML as suggested above and setting the visibility wasn't working, perhaps your syntax was wrong? This is how you programmatically hide an element:

```
element.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```